# How to call jquery function from django template

Tags: jquery, python, django, function, templates

I have a function in my script.js, say function f, and I want to call it from the Django template if a certain variable, called x, is True. 
For example:

```
<div id="about">{% if x %} (CALL f from script.js) {% endif %}</div>
```

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you are on the right track:

```
<div id="about">
  {% if x %} 
    <script src="/script.js" ></script>
    <script>
      f();    // assuming f() is defined in script.js
    </script>
  {% endif %}
</div>
```